# Allow user toggles between several calendars apps within the home page in SharePoint development

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-apps, sharepoint-deployment

I have three calendar apps in site of Sharepoint.

I would like to enable users to stay on the home page and simply be able to toggle through all these calendars, WITHIN the home page, rather than jumping off the home page into full-page views of those other calendars.

I want simply list the calendars' name as dropdown list, and based on the option that user selected the web part below will display the required calendar app.

"Pick One: [Calendar 1]  [Calendar 2]  [Calendar 3]"

Could someone tell me how I can do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options and are you doing this out of the box or a no code approach? What version of SharePoint are you on?

Option 1: Put it into a carousel and let them click through the different calendars.

Option 2: Stack the calendars one on top of each other.  Create a WebPart calendar and display them on the page.  Call the specific view that you want.